# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function

Tags: pyspark, typeerror, user-defined-functions, outliers

I am performing outlier detection in my pyspark dataframe. For that I am using an custom outlier function from [here](https://deepnote.com/@rajshekar-2021/Outlier-Detection-Pyspark-069e69af-2c1d-4d4d-884a-92aad276d06f)

```
def find_outliers(df):

    # Identifying the numerical columns in a spark dataframe
    numeric_columns = [column[0] for column in df.dtypes if column[1] in ['int','float','long']]

    # Using the `for` loop to create new columns by identifying the outliers for each feature
    for column in numeric_columns:

        #less_Q1 = 'less_Q1_{}'.format(column)
        less_Q1 = f'less_Q1_{column}'
        more_Q3 = 'more_Q3_{}'.format(column)
        Q1 = 'Q1_{}'.format(column)
        Q3 = 'Q3_{}'.format(column)

        # Q1 : First Quartile ., Q3 : Third Quartile
        Q1 = df.approxQuantile(column,[0.25],relativeError=0)
        Q3 = df.approxQuantile(column,[0.75],relativeError=0)
        
        # IQR : Inter Quantile Range
        # We need to define the index [0], as Q1 & Q3 are a set of lists., to perform a mathematical operation
        # Q1 & Q3 are defined seperately so as to have a clear indication on First Quantile & 3rd Quantile
        IQR = Q3[0] - Q1[0]
        
        #selecting the data, with -1.5*IQR to + 1.5*IQR., where param = 1.5 default value
        less_Q1 =  Q1[0] - 1.5*IQR
        more_Q3 =  Q3[0] + 1.5*IQR
        
        isOutlierCol = 'is_outlier_{}'.format(column)
        
        df = df.withColumn(isOutlierCol,f.when((df[column] > more_Q3) | (df[column] < less_Q1), 1).otherwise(0))
#         display(df)
    

    # Selecting the specific columns which we have added above, to check if there are any outliers
    selected_columns = [column for column in df.columns if column.startswith("is_outlier")]
#     print(selected_columns)

    # Adding all the outlier columns into a new colum "total_outliers", to see the total number of outliers
    df = df.withColumn('total_outliers',sum(df[column] for column in selected_columns))

    # Dropping the extra columns created above, just to create nice dataframe., without extra columns
    df = df.drop(*[column for column in df.columns if column.startswith("is_outlier")])

    return df
```

When I am running the below code , it is giving me error

```
new_train = find_outliers(final_matrix)
display(new_train)
```

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <generator object
> find_outliers.. at 0x7f19f4423b30> of type <class
> 'generator'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or
> 'create_map' function.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-5331290> in <module>
----> 1 new_train = find_outliers(final_matrix)
      2 display(new_train)

<command-5331289> in find_outliers(df)
     37 
     38     # Adding all the outlier columns into a new colum "total_outliers", to see the total number of outliers
---> 39     df = df.withColumn('total_outliers',sum(df[column] for column in selected_columns))
     40 
     41     # Dropping the extra columns created above, just to create nice dataframe., without extra columns

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in sum(col)
    186     Aggregate function: returns the sum of all values in the expression.
    187     """
--> 188     return _invoke_function_over_column("sum", col)
    189 
    190 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in _invoke_function_over_column(name, col)
     65     and wraps the result with :class:`~pyspark.sql.Column`.
     66     """
---> 67     return _invoke_function(name, _to_java_column(col))
     68 
     69 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _to_java_column(col)
     44         jcol = _create_column_from_name(col)
     45     else:
---> 46         raise TypeError(
     47             "Invalid argument, not a string or column: "
     48             "{0} of type {1}. "

TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <generator object find_outliers.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f19f4248660> of type <class 'generator'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Also this function is working perfectly fine, for one of the pyspark dataframe but for another it is giving error.

Earlier my column names where in numbers, i tried changing that, but still the issue exists.
Can someone tell me where am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: note- check if all required dtypes are listed in the function -- your df can also have `bigint`

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.withColumn('total_outliers',sum(df[column] for column in selected_columns))
```

This `sum` is the built-in python function, you need to use the pyspark `sum` version

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('total_outliers',F.sum(*[df[column] for column in selected_columns]))
```

Comment: This is giving error as: `TypeError: sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'´

Comment: then it sounds like `selected_columns` is an empty list

Comment: yes it was due to empty list, thank you